# Controlling sound output volume of Cocoa WebView

Tags: objective-c, macos, webkit, audio

Is where any way of controlling an individual WebView's sound output volume, or even for the entire application in Cocoa? I don't want to resort to using something like Audio Hijack Pro to control the output volume in the application, nor do I want to have to raise/lower the system volume.

The WebView loads a flash file that has audio playing and I want to control the volume with a NSSlider.